# Mobile physics engine

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm looking to use a physics engine for a 3D mobile game that I'm working on. I'd like to use a library that supports fixed point math and preferably coded in C++.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two major *open source* players are:

- [Bullet](http://www.bulletphysics.org/)
- [ODE](http://opende.sourceforge.net/)

I don't think either of them allow for fixed point types, however. Both are written in C++, although the ODE API is in C.